# How to add extra class in main menu?

Tags: 7, theming, routes

I'm creating custom theme. I am struggling to create main menu with drop down. I created a menu with custom code:

```
 <?php 
            $main_menu_tree = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
            print drupal_render($main_menu_tree);
          ?>
```

But it doesn't working as I want. I need to add class in that particular `<UL>` tags. How can I achieve that?

I tried to Hook custom function in templates file. But no luck. How to call custom function into view page?

Below are some more screenshots.

**Main menu with correct:**

[image: Main menu with correct]

**Menu with Wrong:**

[image: main menu with wrong]

How to call custom menu design in custom theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Menu Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) Module to add classes.

> This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes
>   for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.

To custom code it, you can add class to menu links using [hook_menu_link_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7) . Try something like this:

```
$item['options']['attributes']['class'] = array('class-one' , 'class-two');
```